# How does the HTML call the validation routine?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code and I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me as I am not 100% sure on how it calls the validation routine. I think I know which part does it but I do not know how/what it actually does. Maybe someone could help me out here? c:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Exam entry</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function validateForm(){
     var result = true;
     var msg="";
     if (document.ExamEntry.name.value==""){
       msg+="You must enter your name \n";
       document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
       document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
       result = false;
     }
     if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value==""){
       msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
       document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
       document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
       result = false;
     }
     if(msg==""){
       return result;
     }
     else {
       alert(msg);
       return result;
     }
   }
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
  <form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
   <table width="50%" border="0">
    <tr>
     <td id="name">Name</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td id="subject">Subject</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"   
          onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
     <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

The line where I think it calls the validation is this:

```
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
```

Comment: Fun fact: You can throw all that JavaScript out and just do `<input type="text" name="name"` ***`required`*** `/>`

Answer (score 4):

The line that calls the validation routine is this one :

```
onclick="return validateForm();"
```

Which literally calls `validateForm` on button click.

Answer (score 1):

No. It calls the validation here (at the submit button):

```
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"   
      onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the submit button - you'll find the call to **validateForm()**.

Answer (score -1):

`if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value==""){
       msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
       document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
       document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
       result = false;`

Comment: How does your educational qualifications relate to the answer?